# First installation and Conda is not working correctly. Error (699)

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

First time when I downloaded Anaconda and tried to install scikit-learn (version 0.24.2) in my own environment I realized that it is not checking but installing through Anaconda Navigator. Then I tried to install it manually with help of cmd and conda.exe (conda install -n DeepLearning scikit-learn) and started to get super strange errors, which I can't find in Google.

I decided to do some work that can help, install Conda on C (SSD) and not installing anything but just update all libraries (conda update --all) as scikit-learn is always being installed not up to date. And that is what I am getting:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-0.24.2-py38hf11a4ad_0'.
Rolling back transaction: / menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 74, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda\\Menu\\notebook.jso| menuinst Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 246, in make_menu
    menuinst.install(join(prefix, win_path_ok(file_path)), remove, prefix)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 74, in install
    _install(path, remove, prefix, mode='user')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\menuinst\__init__.py", line 33, in _install
    data = json.load(open(path))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda\\Menu\\notebook.jsodone

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::scikit-learn-0.24.2-py38hf11a4ad_0
location of failed script: C:\Anaconda\Scripts\.scikit-learn-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: "chcp" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
"chcp" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
"find" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

return code: 255

()
```

I've tried almost everything and do not know what to do. Please, help me.

P.S. I haven't encoded anything it is how it looks like.
[Screen of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPceb.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the conda installation/update script incorrectly pass in path of "C:\Anaconda\Menu\notebook.json" as "C:\Anaconda\Menu\notebook.jso". Even if you fix this error, the next error it is going to complain is "C:\Anaconda\Menu\anaconda-navigator.jso"

The workaround is:

1. Navigate to C:\Anaconda\Menu\
2. Rename notebook.json to notebook.jso
3. Rename anaconda-navigator.json to anaconda-navigator.jso
4. Rerun conda installation/update
5. Revert step #2 and #3 once #4 is successful

Comment: I also had to create a `notebook.jso` (just an empty file), since there was no such file in the corresponding subfolder of my installation directory. And the `spyder_shortcut.json` had to be renamed as well. What an incredibly stupid bug. But the workaround fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a ton! `KW Lam`
Its worked form me 
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9939

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order:

1. `conda config`
2. `conda init`
3. `conda update conda`